# MySQL / PostGIS Database File Type

Tags: mysql, postgis

I am trying to recover a database created in PostGIS and hosted here (under resources):

https://github.com/cecois/dossin_art_api

I am able to download the file and open it as a text file but I do not know the file type extension which I should use to import this file into MySQL or view it in a meaningful way. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a PostgreSQL archive file created by [pg_dump](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/app-pgdump.html), which doesn't necessarily have any particular file type extension. Use [pg_restore](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/app-pgrestore.html) to restore the file to a PostreSQL database. You will need to install PostgreSQL and PostGIS, if you haven't already done.

First create an empty database:

```
CREATE DATABASE altartlas;
```

Then connect to this database, and spatially enable it (requires PostGIS to be installed):

```
CREATE EXTENSION postgis;
```

Now from the system console, restore the file to the database:

```
pg_restore -U postgres -O -d altartlas altartlas_db
```

---

Realistically, it would probably be simpler to request the original author for the data in a simpler format (CSV, Shapefile, etc.)

Comment: Hello, yes it would be simpler to request the original data but the author does not have it anymore, just this file.  I tried following what you said but it still did not work.  It says that "Geometry Columns is not a table".  The original author said that that might be a "view" instead of a "table" but did not know how to work around it.  Do you have any ideas?  Thanks.

Comment: For PostGIS 2.0 `geometry_columns` was changed from a table to a view, but this shouldn't matter, and that error can be ignored. Use pgAdmin III to see the tables and the data in the `geometry_columns` view.